# Laravel 5: Guzzle with Chumper Datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable, guzzle

I was wondering if there's a way to integrate this with guzzle? I'm calling an external restful api. I'm new to Datatable so not sure if it's possible. Right now i'm just doing a foreach in my view. How to integrate this with chumper datatable?

**Controller**

```
public function getIndex() {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->get('http://api.company.com/members');
    $body = json_decode($response->getBody());
    $content = view('members')->with('members',$body);
    return Admin::view($content, 'Members');
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($members as $member)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $member->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $member->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $member->phone }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```